# rewrite rule in htaccess rewrite/redirect no longer existing url link

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have some old urls like

```
http://www.domain.com/constant-path1/variable1.htm
```

and the actually url should be

```
http://www.domain.com/constant-path1/variable1.htm/1
```

how to redirect the unexisting old url to the new url to get rid of google spider error?

i wrote a rule like this, but not working:

```
RewriteRule ^constant-path1/([^.]+).htm$ http://www.domain.com/constant-path1/$1.htm/1 [R=301,NC]
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this the only rule there or there are more rules?

Comment: more rules, and all other rules work just fine.

Comment: make this your first rule.

Comment: tried. still not working

Comment: Which URL did you enter to test? Can you open `http://www.domain.com/constant-path1/variable1.htm/1` fine?

Comment: guess u have no clue either. anybody else can help?

Comment: Clues are derived based on the information provided. I asked some question for you in previous comment.